# Validation in Mobile number

Tags: android

Its Validation in Android : 
 User will use  these mobile format case  in EditText box at login time
Note : country code will be any .
 1. Only contact no. , like : 7042955698
2.  0 + contact no. , like 0 7042955698
3. Country code + contact no. , Like  91 7042955698
4."+" + Country code + contact no. , Like  +91 7042955698
5.  00 + country code + contact no. , like 00 91 7042955698
 From this we should get only contact no.
How can be solve this problem?
Thanks in Advance!! cheers

Answer (score 0):

please try in these two ways,
1. Use a device default phone matching pattern to check the number validation in if-else like,

```
android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(editText.getText().toString()).matches()
```

2. Create your own pattern for mobile number and validate using if-else. (pattern should be in a string format to compare) like

```
if (editText.getText().toString().matches(your_contact_Pattern))
```

Hope it helps logically.

Comment: How I will check country code like +33 for France , 971 UAE

Comment: From the first option only (since it is device configured country-wise set format) . Not sure, how to figure out from second option.

Comment: Sure I will try first case ... Thanks